# Footer image doesn't stick to the bottom

Tags: html, css, image

I use a footer here: http://bit.ly/1dnluzM 
It has an image which always should be 100% wide. Also it should scale down proportionally when windows is smaller than 1920px.

I don't know why there is a small gap between bottom of the page and this image. Firebug doesn't show any margin or padding. I guess this is somehow with rescaling image.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="page-wrap">
<div class="nasze-menu">           
    <img  usemap="#menu" src="images/main.png" alt="Lody Bonano - Menu">
    <map name="menu">
    <area shape="poly" coords="463,390,463,531,357,532,291,389" href="/" alt="Shape 3 Shape Path" title="Shape 3 Shape Path" id="kielich">
    <area shape="poly" coords="537,209,536,247,782,252,783,207" href="/" alt="Strona główna" title="Strona główna" id="goback">

    </map>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.site-footer {
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index: 5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try making image a block element

i.e

```
.site-footer img
{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you very much. As soon as I can, I will mark your answer as Solved :)